# Clojure: creating a macro to quote every symbols of a map

Tags: macros, clojure

I am trying to write a macro that takes a map as input, and that will quote every symbol that exists in that map (keys & values).

Here is what I would like to do. Let's say I have a macro `quote-everything` that take a map like this as input:

```
{foo "foo" :bar bar}
```

Then, evaluating:

```
(quote-everything {foo "foo" :bar bar})
```

Would produce:

```
{quote(foo) "foo" :bar quote(bar)}
```

Basically, I want the macro to generate a new map where every symbols are quoted. The problem is that I am don't know where to start, and if it is even possible.  The thing is that the map can be anything, and the macro **should support nested maps** as well.

The detection of the symbols could be done using `symbol?`. However, to support nested maps the macro should probably call itself. But I have no idea how the new map should be created with such a macro.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with just quoting the map at the top level? How does that not meet your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clojure.walk/postwalk` might help you here:

```
(require '[clojure.walk :as w])
(w/postwalk 
  (fn [x] 
    (if (symbol? x)
      `(quote ~x)
      x))
  '{foo :foo :bar bar})
;; => {(quote foo) :foo, :bar (quote bar)}
```

Wrap that in a `defmacro` and it should get you started. Note that that really quotes every symbol, so if you have something like `(inc 1)` in there it will end up as `((quote inc) 1)`. That might actually be what you want, I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: wonderful, this is exactly what I was looking for (postwalk). From there, I will be able to tweak it for what I need to do, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `quote` special form already does this for you:

```
user> (= (quote {foo "foo" :bar bar})
         {(quote foo) "foo" :bar (quote bar)})
;; => true
```

All quotation does is prevents a form from being evaluated. I think you might be making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: this is really good to know! In fact, I probably should have specified that my question was really about being able to do that kind of things (with postwalk) to modify a map and returned the modified one than the `quote` itself. In any case, this is good go know that `quote` works that way.